# convert fraction into string and also insert [] for repeating part

Tags: c++, c, string, algorithm, fractions

An interview question:

Given two int N (numerator) and D (denominator), return the fraction in string. if the fraction is repeating, then display the repeating part in bracket.

Example:
Input: N=1, D=3
output: 0.[3]

Example:
Input: N=2, D=5
output: 0.4

My idea:

get a = N/D with double value.

for part after decimal point,  get each digit by x 10 
in the process, if find repeating, record the index and insert [] finally.

for part before decimal point,  get each digit by / 10

Any better ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

I would avoid using a double like the plague. Due to finite precision, it will not give you the correct answer. Stick to integer arithmetic and simulate [long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division), keeping track of the remainder. After you run out of digits in the numerator (so you are bringing down zeros), also keep a history of remainders and if you see a remainder that is already in the history, that tells you that you have hit a repeating sequence. You can then construct the bracketed output part. (If you hit a zero remainder, of course, that means that the answer is a terminating fraction.)

Comment: Yep. And [the code in this answer to a different related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8455604/968261) can help with the long division of the numerator and denominator and remainders.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rust solution which simulates long division for the fractional part.

There will only be a repeating decimal if the divisor has a factor other than 2 and 5. We can easily check for this by repeatedly dividing by 2 until all factors of 2 are removed and then repeatedly dividing by 5 until all factors of 5 are removed. After dividing, if the resultant number is 1, then there will be no repeating decimal.

To handle the case for the repeating decimal, we keep a hashset of the remainders we have seen until now. If a remainder reappears, we stop the computation.

```
#[allow(unused_variables)]

use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let a = read_usize();
    let b = read_usize();
    println!("{}", long_division(a, b));
}

fn read_usize() -> usize {
    let mut input_string = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input_string)
        .expect("failed to read from stdin");
    let trimmed = input_string.trim();
    let num = trimmed.parse::<usize>().unwrap();
    num
}

fn repeating_decimal(denominator: usize) -> bool {
    let mut d = denominator;
    while d % 2 == 0 {
        d /= 2;
    }
    while d % 5 == 0 {
        d /= 5;
    }
    if d == 1 { false } else { true }
}

fn long_division(a: usize, b: usize) -> String {
    let q = a / b;
    let r = (a % b) * 10;
    if r == 0 {
        return q.to_string();
    }
    if repeating_decimal(b) {
        format!("{}.({})",q,divide_repeating_decimal(r, b))
    } else {
        format!("{}.{}",q,divide_without_repeating_decimal(r, b))
    }

}

fn divide_repeating_decimal(mut r: usize, b: usize) -> String {
    let mut result = String::new();
    let mut seen: HashSet<usize> = HashSet::new();
    loop {
        if r < b {
            r *= 10;
            result.push_str(&"0".to_owned());
            continue;
        }
        let q = r / b;
        r = (r % b) * 10;
        result.push_str(&q.to_string());
        if seen.contains(&r) {
            break;
        }
        seen.insert(r.clone());

    }
    result
}

fn divide_without_repeating_decimal(mut r: usize, b: usize) -> String {
    let mut result = String::new();
    while r != 0 {
        if r < b {
            r *= 10;
            result.push_str(&"0".to_owned());
            continue;
        }
        let q = r / b;
        r = (r % b) * 10;
        result.push_str(&q.to_string());
    }
    result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For fixed point, simply multiply the numerator with 10 before dividing. For floating point, simply use division then `modf` to get the fractional part. In either case, convert to string then format as preferred (1 decimal).

In C you could do something generic that handles either fixed or floating point, by use of `_Generic`.

A simple example without any error handling:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

char* strfract_int (char* dst, int n, int d)
{
  sprintf(dst, "0.%d", n*10 / d);
  return dst;
}

char* strfract_double (char* dst, double n, double d)
{
  double dummy;
  sprintf(dst, "%.1f", modf(n/d, &dummy) );
  return dst;
}

#define strfract(dst, n, d)                   \
  _Generic((n),                               \
           int:    strfract_int,              \
           double: strfract_double)(dst,n,d)  \

int main (void)
{
  char buf [100];
  puts( strfract(buf, 1, 3) );
  puts( strfract(buf, 2, 5) );
  puts( strfract(buf, 1.0, 3.0) );
  puts( strfract(buf, 2.0, 5.0) );
}
```

In a rugged program, check for division against zero, the result of malloc etc etc.